# Grep for the closest occurrence of line before pattern

Tags: grep

I would like to search the file with GREP for the "User-Agent: UA" and then extract the closest line above that has "Via:" My problem is that sometimes there are multiple lines with "Via:", but I need only last one.

For example file to parse:

```
Via: 1.1.1.1  
not relevant line  
...
not relevant line N
User-Agent: UA
...
Via: 2.2.2.2
Via: 3.3.3.3
not relevant line
...
not relevant line N
User-Agent: UA
...
Via: 4.4.4.4
Via: 5.5.5.5
Via: 6.6.6.6
not relevant line
...
not relevant line N
User-Agent: UA
```

Result I want is the lines that contain "Via:" closest to "User-Agent: UA"

```
Via: 1.1.1.1
Via: 3.3.3.3
Via: 6.6.6.6
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

You could do it with `awk` like so:

```
 awk '/Via/ {via_line=$0} /User-Agent: UA/ {print via_line}' input_file
```

so we'll find every line that contains `Via` and store that line, overwriting any previous one, then when we find the `User-Agent: UA` line print whatever we have stored for the `Via` lines.

Comment: You're right, === were not part of output, edited question. Your solution works like charm!

Comment: @OrestOrestovych glad to help.  If that solved your problem you can accept the answer by clicking the check mark by it, that will let others who find your question know what worked for you, let others know you've already found an answer, and you and I will each get some reputation for it

Answer (score 3):

With sed:

```
sed -n '/^Via/h;/^User-Agent: UA$/{g;p;}' file
```

Output:

```
Via: 1.1.1.1  
Via: 3.3.3.3
Via: 6.6.6.6
```

Suppress automatic printing of pattern space with `-n`. If a line starts with `Via` copy pattern space to hold space (`h`). This overwrites hold space. If a line contains "User-Agent: UA" copy hold space to pattern space (`g`) and print pattern space (`p`).

Comment: Use the negated form to golf it shorter: `sed '/^Via/h;/^User-Agent: UA$/!d;x'`