# grep pattern before another pattern and print it all

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep

Given intput:

```
Via: 1.1.1.1  
not relevant line  
keyword + some text
...
not relevant line N
keyword + some text
...
not relevant line N
Via: 2.2.2.2
not relevant line  
keyword + some text
...
not relevant line N
keyword + some text
...
not relevant line N
Via: 3.3.3.3
not relevant lines
Via: 4.4.4.4
not relevant
Via: 5.5.5.5
not relevant line  
keyword + some text
...
not relevant line N
keyword + some text
...
not relevant line N
not relevant line N
...
```

Required output:

```
Via: 1.1.1.1  
keyword + some text A
keyword + some text A
Via: 2.2.2.2
keyword + some text B
keyword + some text C
Via: 5.5.5.5
keyword + some text D
keyword + some text E
```

keyword string can occur N times in any Via block, or may not occur at all. In the output I need only those Via blocks where keyword occurs together with keyword strings belonging to them. The closest answer I found is [*here*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/287236/grep-for-the-closest-occurrence-of-line-before-pattern), but I can't make it into what I need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `sed`:

```
sed -n '/^Via:/{ x; /keyword/p; d; }; /keyword/H; ${ x; /keyword/p; }' input.txt
```

Or, if you want `keyword` anchored at the beginning of line:

```
sed -n '/^Via:/{ x; /\nkeyword/p; d; }; /^keyword/H; ${ x; /\nkeyword/p; }' input.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

**Awk** solution:

```
awk '/^Via:/{ f=1; r=$0; kw=0; next }
     f && /keyword/{ printf "%s%s\n",(!kw)? r ORS:"",$0; kw++ }' file
```

---

- `/^Via:/` - capturing line starting with `Via:` into `r` variable. Set flag `f=1` into "active" state indicating processing of a certain `Via` block
- `kw` - flag denoting the number of *"keyword"* lines under each `Via` block
- `f && /keyword/` - while processing lines under `Via` block - consider only lines matching `keyword` pattern

Answer (score 0):

easy-peasy and simple:

```
cat input.txt | grep "Via:\|keyword" | grep -B1 "keyword"
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note that [brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).